# NEHotspotHelperの導入方法について

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

お世話になります。
http://qiita.com/naokits/items/aa16e1553880c7ddbfbf
上記のページを参考に、Network Extensionの許可の問い合わせを行い、許可を受け画像の通りEntitlementsの箇所にNetwork Extensionが表示されました。

[image: Apple Developer program]

ですが、下記のコードを実行した際に、interfacesの中に何も入ってこないです。

```
func printRetrievedWifiNetwork() {
    let interfaces = NEHotspotHelper.supportedNetworkInterfaces()
    print("--- \(interfaces)") // Appleの許可が得られているのに、ここに何も入ってこない

    for interface in interfaces as! [NEHotspotNetwork] {
        print("--- \(interfaces)")
        let ssid = interface.ssid
        let bssid = interface.bssid
        let secure = interface.isSecure
        let autoJoined = interface.didAutoJoin
        let signalStrength = interface.signalStrength

        print("ssid: \(ssid)")
        print("bssid: \(bssid)")
        print("secure: \(secure)")
        print("autoJoined: \(autoJoined)")
        print("signalStrength: \(signalStrength)")
    }
}
```

NEHotspotHelperの導入方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/60458

Answer (score 1):

以下のNEHotspotHelperのクラスメソッドを実行する必要があります。

```
func register(options: [String : NSObject]? = nil, queue: DispatchQueue, handler: @escaping NEHotspotHelperHandler) -> Bool
```

このメソッドを実行後に、あなたのアプリを一旦バックグラウンドにして、設定アプリのWi-Fiの画面に行くとHandlerに結果が却ってきますので、そこで初めてリストを取得できます。

参考
http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/ios-nehotspothelper/
https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2016/11/02/working-with-nehotspothelper/